# Simulink: PV System (Need help with the voltage regulator part)

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, control-system, matlab, simulink

I have been trying to model a PV system for a household. The scheme is as shown in the diagram. Its just a PV that connects to a boost converter then eventually an inverter. I have properly managed to get a 240 AC output.

I want to create a voltage regulator that regulates the voltage at 240V DC (before going thru the inverter) when a voltage drop occurs. I have tried the tutorials in Youtube etc. but they don't really explain in details.

P.S: the blocks below are some of the things I've tried to regulate the voltage with and ends up just ruining the output of the converter and PV.

extra P.S: I have tried using the DC voltage controller but it somehow outputs 24V? and the PV also outputs 24V?

[image: Simulink Diagram]

Comment: The main part of the circuit seems to have the PV, boost and inverter circuits. Where is the voltage regulator ? Can't you integrate the voltage regulator into the boost circuit itself ? Currently it seems to be run by fixed duty cycle PWM. IMO, the diagram provided is insufficient to understand the circuit behavior.

Comment: Unless you can control (disconnect part of) the load, you need an additional source of power ... i.e, a battery.

Comment: Yes, the above diagram is currently using a fixed duty cycle through the PWM generator. I was hoping to get an idea of how to design a voltage regulator for my DC-DC Boost.

Like how MPPT work, instead of maximum power i want a constant voltage output of 240 V.

https://imgur.com/a/i5Gtesq

This is my updated and cleaner looking circuit. Thank you to anyone who helped!